# How Composer can handle attachments in Assets and/or transactions?

Tags: attachment, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I've gone through the play ground demos and I am trying to build one prototype for the Letter of Credit use case and was wondering how attachments can be handled within Assets and/or transactions.

Answer (score 0):

We don't yet have a great solution for this, but are interested in requirements and use cases. You could model the attached as a URL and a hash (2 strings in your model) and host the attachments on an external secure document store.

You submit a transaction which carries the URL and the hash of the document to Composer, which updates the asset with the attachment. When the attachment for an asset is required you can query the asset via the REST API, retrieve the linked document from the secure doc store and then compare its hash with the hash on the asset.

Comment: Is this something can be added into playground? Or may be an Attachment type in the data model? So once its defined playground allows to upload and download attachments. In the letter of credit example the entire process could have few documents which we may have to keep track of. See one blockchain demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wkkIaemSw4)